# how does CATransform3DTranslate do translate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I know that the CATransform3D is defined as

```
struct CATransform3D
{
CGFloat m11, m12, m13, m14;

CGFloat m21, m22, m23, m24;

CGFloat m31, m32, m33, m34;

CGFloat m41, m42, m43, m44;
};
```

and the Apple document says that

```
CATransform3DTranslate
Translate 't' by '(tx, ty, tz)' and return the result: t' = translate(tx, ty, tz) * t.
```

I want to implement my CATransform3DTranslate method, but I don't know exactly how to calculate the t', i.e. I have the transform like `self.layer.transform`, and tx = 10, ty=tz=0, how to calculate get the t'?

Comment: If you really want to know I can recommend [my long post here of all the math involved](http://ronnqvi.st/the-math-behind-transforms/).

Comment: Print the result and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to.
You just use CATransform3dMakeTranslation method on a layer, you set the input values and game!
CATransform3dMakeTranslation (like CATransform3DMakeRotation) will do all the math tho have a rototranslation matrix of coordinate change. You don't have to worry about the matrix itself if all you want is to translate/rotate/rototranslate a layer in the 3d space.